# Silero скорость воспроизведения как замедлить?

Tags: python, pytorch, tts

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как замедлить скорость голоса ? Слишком он быстрый, другие "speaker" тоже пробовал, они не меняют скорость. Нужно на английском (хотя если это возможно сделать, то будет работать и с русской моделью)

```
import torch
import sounddevice as sd

language = 'en'
model_id = 'v3_en'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'en_5'
device = torch.device('cpu')

example_text = '''Today is the last day of school.
It is summer vacation.
Grace is very excited.
This summer will be fun.
Grace is going to visit her Grandparents.
They have a cottage.'''

model, _ = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                          model='silero_tts',
                          language=language,
                          speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        )
sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
sd.wait()
sd.stop()
```

Comment: Решил задачу таким способом:
в audio нужно заменить 
```audio = model.apply_tts(ssml_text=text, speaker=speaker, sample_rate=sample_rate)
```
И в самом тексте место которое хочешь замедлить обернуть в тег <prosody rate="slow">Текст </prosody>. И обязательно весь текст обернуть в <speak> </speak>

Comment: не ориентируюсь в теме, но добавил в отслеживаемое, чтобы узнать что да как. Попробовал поискать, ничего дельного не нашёл. Оформи в ответ, если не сложно, думаю будет полезно тем кто ищет. Отвечать на свой вопрос в порядке правил )

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу таким способом: в audio нужно заменить 'text' на 'ssml_text':

```
audio = model.apply_tts(ssml_text=text, speaker=speaker, sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

И в самом тексте (который хочешь преобразовать) место которое хочешь замедлить обернуть в тег

```
<prosody rate="slow">Текст </prosody>
```

И обязательно весь текст обернуть в

```
<speak> </speak>
```